# ARM assembly how to print string index

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I have been stuck on this program for a while now and have not been able to figure out what the problem is.

I have looked on here as well as my college textbook and cannot find a clear answer. The answers that I have seen use C functions to handle the output, I am trying to stay away from C because I really want to understand how Assembly works.

Anyways, the program below does 2 things. The first thing it does is loop x number of times and print "hello" to the console each iteration. Everything is working fine in this section of the program

The second part is also a loop, but instead of printing a string, I only want to print an index of the string.

This is an example in C of what i'm trying to do:

```
char hello[6] = "Hello";
int len = 6;

for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    printf("%c\n", hello[i]);
}
```

This is where I am having trouble, it is not printing anything at all. I have tried the following instructions to print the character value to the console: `MOV` `LDR` `LDRB`.

I know this is probably something very simple, any help is appreciated.

Here is the code, I've commented everything to show what 'I think' is happening:

```
/* 
 * Program:     String Loop
 *
 * Author:      
 *
 * Date:        1/29/20
 *
 * Purpose:     Learning ARM Assembly Language
 */




.text
.global main

main:

    printString:
        MOV R3, #0      @ Store counter in r3
        MOV R4, #5      @ Max iterations for loop1

        loop1:
            @ Print String
            MOV R7, #4          @ Syscall Write   
            MOV R0, #1          @ Output to monitor
            LDR R2, =len        @ Buffer size
            LDR R1, =message    @ Addr of string 
            SWI 0               @ Interrupt

            ADD R3, R3, #1      @ Incr counter
            CMP R3, R4          @ Compare counter/max iterations
            BLT loop1           @ If counter < max, loop again


    printChar:
        LDR R4, =message        @ Load string addr into r4

        loop2:
            LDRB R5, [R4], #1   @ Get next char of string
            CMP R5, #0          @ See if char is #0
            BEQ exit            @ If so, exit

            @ Print Char
            MOV R7, #4      
            MOV R0, #1      
            MOV R2, #1 
            MOV R1, R5      // Also tried LDR R1, [R5] && LDRB R1, [R5]
            SWI 0    

            B loop2

exit:
    MOV R7, #1
    SWI 0

.data
    message: 
        .ascii "Hello\n"
    len = .-message

.end
```

Comment: The `write` system call expects `R1` to contain _the address_ of the data to write. So that's what you'll have to give it.

Comment: Also it's unclear what you want to do. What do you mean "index of the string"?

Comment: @Jester I updated the question with an example of what i'm trying to do, thanks.

Comment: In that case, replace `MOV R1, R5` with `SUB R1, R4, #1` (assuming that the system call doesn't clobber `R4`).

Comment: So basically you want to print the string again, but not with a `*ptr++` but with a `ptr[i++]`? You will obviously need an `i` then. So allocate a register for it, increment it, test for the end condition. As for loading the char, use that register as offset, e.g. `add r1, r4, rX` (where `rX` is your `i`)

Comment: Thank you both for the quick replies, I have tried replacing `MOV R1, R5` with `SUB R1, R4, #1` and also tried `ADD R1, R4, rX`. They are both giving a segmentation fault.

Comment: Nevermind @Jester you are right, thank you!

Comment: @Michael I got your solution to work also, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
    message1: 
        .ascii "Hello\n"
    len1 = . - message1
    message2:
        .byte 0
    len2 = . - message2
.text
.global _start
_start:
    ldr r0, =message2
    ldr r1, =len2
    ldr r3, =message1
    ldr r4, =len1
    mov r5, #0
    loop$:
        ldr r6, [r3, r4]
        strb r6, [r0]
        bl print
        cmp r5, r4
        addlt r4, #1
        blt loop$
    mov r7, #1
    mov r0, #0
    svc #0
print:
    mov r2, r1
    mov r1, r0
    mov r0, #1
    mov r7, #4
    svc #0
    mov pc, lr
```